# Vectorized permutations

Tags: r, vectorization, permutation

I have an array of 12 objects. Each is a letter. I want to generate all combinations of 4, 5, 6, 7 and 8 letters.

First I just generate the permutations using `gregmisc` package:

```
sapply(4:8, function(x) permutations(n = 12, r = x)) -> perms
```

Then I want to take the array of objects called `letters.split` and I want to create all combos. So I go:

```
unlist(lapply(perms, a <- function (x){
        apply(x, 1, function(y) letters.split[y])
    })) -> combos
```

It seems pretty computationally inefficient..takes a while. There must be a better way to use the permutation combos at an index. The permutations function isn't really what bothers me because I only have to do it ones then I can just save it.

I want to ask if there's a vectorized way of doing this but I don't actually know what that means so a simple explanation of what a vectorized function in simple terms would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm not entirely clear what you're asking, though it seems like you may simply be trying to recreate the `combn` function?

Comment: The second step does not look necessary: the `permutations` function has a `v` argument that can directly permute your data, without having to consider the indices: `lapply( 4:6, permutations, n=8, v=LETTERS[1:12] )`.

Comment: Ask "What is a vectorised function?" in a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Answer goes to Vincent Zoonekynd.

The second step does not look necessary: the `permutations` function of `vegan` package has a `v` argument that can directly permute your data, without having to consider the indices:

```
x <- lapply(2:3, permutations, n = 3, v = LETTERS[1:12])
```

Output:

```
[[1]]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,] "A"  "B" 
[2,] "A"  "C" 
[3,] "B"  "A" 
[4,] "B"  "C" 
[5,] "C"  "A" 
[6,] "C"  "B" 

[[2]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,] "A"  "B"  "C" 
[2,] "A"  "C"  "B" 
[3,] "B"  "A"  "C" 
[4,] "B"  "C"  "A" 
[5,] "C"  "A"  "B" 
[6,] "C"  "B"  "A"
```

II. Vectorized function is a function which takes a vector as an agrument. Usually (esp. in other languages like C) your function takes a single value as an argument so you have to use `for`-loop to cycle through an array.

For example:

Calculate `log10` of for the array of numbers - 1, 10, 100, 1000.

Non-vectorized approach (C-like style):

```
x <- c(1, 10, 100, 1000)
for(i in 1:4) {
  print(log10(x[i]))
}

# [1] 0
# [1] 1
# [1] 2
# [1] 3
```

Vectorized approach. As `log10` is vectorized function, you can use it with vector as an argument.

```
x <- 10 
log10(x)
# [1] 0 1 2 3
```